# Cron <ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-105> /etc/cron.hourly/cron.RDS.sh

Tags: amazon-ec2, cron, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04

i am setting up a cron that needs to be run at every 5 minute. so i kept my shell script at /etc/cron.hourly/cron.RDS.sh which execute my PYTHON script that placed inside some folder. and i a virtualenv which needs to be activated before executing the python script. when i run my shell script directly from the terminal it works fine. but i set the crontab it throwing me an error.
here is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PERIOD="300"

ENDTIME=$(date -u "+%F %H:%M:00" -d "5 minutes ago")

STARTTIME=$(date -u "+%F %H:%M:00" -d "10 minutes ago")

source /home/ubuntu/monitoring/venv/bin/activate

python /home/ubuntu/monitoring/aws-monitoring/autoDiscovery.py -s "RDS" -p "$PERIOD" -f "$STARTTIME" -t "$ENDTIME"
```

here is my crontab

*/5 * * * * /etc/cron.hourly/cron.RDS.sh

i dont know whats the issue.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/monitoring/aws-monitoring/autoDiscovery.py", line 4, in <module>
    from connections import Connection
  File "/home/ubuntu/monitoring/aws-monitoring/connections.py", line 1, in <module>
    import boto3
ImportError: No module named boto3

Comment: i guess virtualenv is getting activated before execution of python script

Comment: Could be. Note that in Bash, it's more common to say `. bin/activate` than `source bin/activate`. Another explanation is that the module search path environment variables `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` are different in your cron script than in your normal shell session - try logging them?